# new phone has locked and asking for password but I haven't set one yet!

Tags: password, lumia-925

my new nokia lumia 925 has locked itself. This morning I tried to use my phone and it is asking for my password! I haven't even set a password yet! Is there a default password on these phones? I can receive calls but that's all. Please help

Comment: What kind of keyboard is used to enter the password? Is it just numbers or is there even letters?

Answer (score 1):

No there default password. Could someone else have set it? Did you buy it from someone?

The only way to access the phone if you can't figure it out is doing a hard reset.

(I'm assuming you're not taking about the Microsoft account but the lockscreen pin)

Comment: Yes just lock screen. It's a new phone and there has not been any screen etc asking for a password set so I definitely haven't set one. I will take it back to shop. Makes no sense to me,never come across this before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can just do a hard reset using the buttons(just google it). This might save you the trip.